# Convert string in #!/bin/sh

Tags: linux, shell, text-processing, string

Hi I have output like this

```
[4251][7c3c]
```

I need to get

```
517C3C
```

I've tried

```
decodeSerial() {
    serial=$1 
    #serial=$serial | sed -r 's/(\[|\])//g'
    #serial=$serial | sed 's/]//'
    #serial=$serial | tr a-z A-Z
    serial=${serial: -6}
    echo $serial
}
```

only last six characters works fine

Comment: In what form is the output? stdout? a variable? in a file?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
$ echo '[4251][7c3c]' | tr -d '[]' | tr '[:lower:]' '[:upper:]' | cut -c 3-
517C3C
```

As a function:

```sh
decodeSerial () {
    printf '%s\n' "$1" |
    tr -d '[]' |
    tr '[:lower:]' '[:upper:]' |
    cut -c 3-
}
```

The pipeline removes all `[` and `]` character from the input, converts any lower-case characters to upper-case, and discards the first two characters from the result.

---

With a single `sed` call (which assumes that the alphabetic characters are hexadecimal digits, `a` through to `f`):

```
$ echo '[4251][7c3c]' | sed 's/[][]//g; y/abcdef/ABCDEF/; s/^..//'
517C3C
```

To keep the last six characters rather than delete the first two, this `sed` call may be changed to

```
sed 's/[][]//g; y/abcdef/ABCDEF/; s/^.*\(.\{6\}\)$/\1/'
```

---

Using `awk`:

```
$ echo '[4251][7c3c]' | awk '{ gsub("[][]", ""); print toupper(substr($1,3)) }'
517C3C
```

Using the `awk` command in your function (the `sed` command above could be inserted in a similar fashion):

```sh
decodeSerial () {
    printf '%s\n' "$1" |
    awk '{ gsub("[][]", ""); print toupper(substr($1,3)) }'
}
```

Using `awk` without a pipeline in the shell function:

```sh
decodeSerial () {
    awk -v string="$1" 'BEGIN { gsub("[][]", "", string); print toupper(substr(string,3)) }'
}
```

Note that your `${serial: -6}` is `bash` syntax which might not work with `/bin/sh`.

Answer (score 0):

You could do that with bash [string-manipulation](https://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/string-manipulation.html):

```bash
serial='[4251][7c3c]' ; serial="${serial//[/}" ; serial="${serial//]/}" ; echo "${serial: -6}"
```

or as a function

```bash
decodeSerial () {
  serial="$1"
  serial="${serial//[/}"
  serial="${serial//]/}"
  printf '%s\n' "${serial: -6}"
}
```

Comment: This is still `bash` syntax though, not generally supported by `/bin/sh`.

Comment: @Kusalananda True. I'm a case of bash-induced tunnel-vision :-)